# Assign negative int to long in java

Tags: java, casting, mask, masking, signed

I've 2 integer values stored in a bytebuffer, in little-endian format. These integers are actually the 32-bit pieces of a long. I've to store them as a class' member variables, `loBits` and `hiBits`.

This is what I did:

```
long loBits = buffer.getInt(offset);
long hiBits = buffer.getInt(offset + Integer.BYTES);
```

I want to know why directly assigning signed int to long is wrong. I kind of know what's going on, but would really appreciate an explanation.

The int I read from the buffer is signed (because Java). If it is negative then directly assigning it to a long value (or casting it like `(long)`) would change all the higher order bits in the long to the signed bit value.

For e.g. Hex representation of an int, `-1684168480` is `9b9da0e0`. If I assign this int to a long, all higher order 32 bits would become `F`.

```
int negativeIntValue = -1684168480;
long val1 = negativeIntValue;
long val2 = (long) negativeIntValue;
```

Hex representation of:

```
negativeIntValue is 0x9b9da0e0
val1 is 0xffffffff9b9da0e0
val2 is 0xffffffff9b9da0e0
```

However, if I mask the `negativeIntValue` with `0x00000000FFFFFFFFL`, I get a long which has the same hex representation as `negativeIntValue` and a positive long value of `2610798816`.

So my questions are:

- Is my understanding correct?
- Why does this happen?

Comment: Two's-complement and sign extension :)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, your understanding is correct (at least if I understood your understanding correctly).

The reason this happens is because (most) computers use [2's complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two's_complement) to store signed values. So when assigning a smaller datatype to a larger one, the value is sign extended meaning that the excess part of the datatype is filled with 0 or 1 bits depending on whether the original value was positive or negative.

Also related is the difference between `>>` and `>>>` operators in Java. The first one performs sign extending (keeping negative values negative) the second one does not (shifting a negative value makes it positive).

Answer (score 1):

The reason for this is that negative values are stored as [two's complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement).

Why do we use two's complement?

In a *fixed width* numbering system what happens, if you substract `1` from `0`?

```
0000b - 0001b -> 1111b
```

and what is the next lesser number to `0`? It is `-1`.

Therfore we thread a binary number with all bits set (for a signed datatype) as `-1`

The big advantage is that the CPU does not need to do any special operation when changing from positive to negative numbers. It handles `5 - 3` the same as `3 - 5`